# Filter by pick flag OR color label?

Tags: lightroom

I'm trying to filter my collection given certain criteria, but I can't find a way to apply filters in a *either-or* fashion. That is, I want to see all fotos in a folder that are either flagged as pick OR have the color label green. If I apply those attributes from the filter panel, I will only get all photos that are flagged as pick AND have the label green.

I have tried using a text-filter (those work with the OR keyword), but apparently the Lightroom metadata is not part of the searchable metadata fields. I also tried using a Smart Collection, but that didn't work out either. If I select *match any of the following rules* I have no way to limit the collection to the folder I'm working on, if I select *match all of the following rules* I have the same problem as with the normal filters …

This simple filtering operation seems like something pretty simple. Am I missing something? How can I combine filters in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is possible, but how about creating a collection set, and in that create two Smart collections, one matching each of the two criteria. When you click the collection set, it will select all images below that level, so should achieve the desired result

Comment: Quite cumbersome for a simple filter, but I suppose it is a workaround

Comment: @MoritzLost yes probably, especially if you've got a lot of other smart collections already, it might get lost among them all

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it can't be done without using third-party plugins. You can try Jeffrey Friedl's [Data Explorer](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/data-explorer), or John Ellis' [Any Filter](http://www.johnrellis.com/lightroom/anyfilter.htm). I haven't had an opportunity to try them myself yet, but both plugins look very capable.